# Material-Table in React. Dynamically setting table options with state variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

Im new to this Material-Table table.  Im trying to set its options based upon what the user selects to do.

For example, I want to turn on/off filtering based upon if the user want to filter or not.

I have a button that sets a state variable true or false depending on when its selected.

```
    this.state = {
        filterStatus:false,
    }
```

But my options property doesnt allow me to use the state variable.

```
     options={{
           filtering: {this.state.filterStatus}
             }}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I want the user to be able to simplily have the option to turn off filtering with a push button.

To go from this,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXt6X.png)

to this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XAeo.png)

Comment: can you be much more specific ?Some example image or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filtering` under `options` in `MaterialTable` as below:

```
<MaterialTable
            title="Basic Filtering Preview"
            columns={state.columns}
            data={state.data}
            options={{
                filtering: state.filtering
            }}
            icons={tableIcons}
        />
```

In this example, I used a `toggle button` to trun off/on  filtering.

**[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-noyce-3s212)**